# Jax-ws: Log request and response in database

Tags: java, jax-ws

I have a web service which contains getEmployeeList method and i need to log request and response in a database like;

```
***Column**  **Id   Request       Response       ResponseTime*** 
               1    Request1      Response1      600ms
               2    Request2      Response2      400ms
```

My employee service class;

```
@WebService
@HandlerChain(file="employeehandler-chain.xml")
public interface EmployeeWS {

@WebMethod
List<Employee> getEmployeeList(
        @WebParam(name = " EmployeeReq")  EmployeeReq  employeeReq);
```

My custom handler class ;

```
public class EmployeeHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

 @Override
 public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {


    Boolean outBound = (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);

    try {
        SOAPMessage soapMsg = context.getMessage();
```

Is there a way to correlate the request and response in my handler ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an id when you are handling an inbound message and save into the `SOAPMessageContext` and get it when you are handling the response:

```
Boolean outBound = (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);

if (!outbound) {
    Long messageId = createId();
    context.put("messageId", messageId);
    saveRequestToDatabase(context.getMessage(), messageId);
} else {
    saveResponseToDatabase(context.getMessage(), context.get("messageId"));
}
```

Each request creates a new `SOAPMessageContext` which is kept alive until the end of the response process, so even if there are various requests being executed concurrently each context will be different.

Comment: You're right. MessageContext interface extends Map<String, Object>, Thank you so much..